# How can I pick a random entry from a list?

Tags: c#

I am using this code to pick a random element from a list:

```
var rand = new Random();
var i = rand.Next(words.Count);
keyword = words[i].keyword;
```

Is this the optimal way to do this or is there a better way that I could employ? What I am particularly concerned about is will this be completely random?

Comment: How random is "completely random"?

Comment: How about `randomizing` the indices of the elements of the list every time you wanna pick a random entry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be absymally un-random, you must **not** create a new `Random` instance each time you need a number. Doing that completely ruins the statistical properties of the generator.

Even then you will not achieve perfect randomness (you need external hardware for that), but it ought to satisfy all the principal properties of randomness.

Comment: "Doing that completely ruins the statistical properties of the generator."  Citation needed.

Comment: Or proof by demonstration: create an x-y plot of repeated `new Random(); x = Next; y = Next` if you get my meaning and inspect the output graphically.

Comment: Is the Random instance based on time?  The timing will be 5-10 seconds apart and based on when a used does a click so would that make it better?

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to create more than one random number, you should keep the Random instance and reuse it. **If you create new instances too close in time, they will produce the same series of random numbers as the random generator is seeded from the system clock**.

**Every time you do new Random() it is initialized . This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same instance.**

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this line for single time initialization: `var rand = new Random();`

Use below code to generate new number each time.

```
var i = rand.Next(words.Count);
keyword = words[i].keyword;
```

Hope it will help you.